# Unable to import name: IP, with Pinject installed? Python

Tags: python

Unable to import, Ip from Pinject, I installed Pinject with Pip, did I forget a package?

```
from pinject import IP, UDP
```

I have installed Pinject with Pip, but still no luck, any help appreciated.

Comment: I take it no one knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced this already. For that you have to download `pinject.py` and paste it in folder which contains`Saddam.py`.

Comment: Telepathic Genius.